# I do not understand the return value of the function below

Tags: python, function, currying

```py
def horse(mask):
    horse = mask
    def mask(horse):
        return horse
    return horse(mask)

mask = lambda horse: horse(2)

horse(mask)
```

After trying this code on Python tutor, it becomes more confusing to me.
I need someone to explain it more clearly.

Comment: Including your code as text makes it searchable by google, that way it might help other people as well.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Re-using scoped variables like this is not good practice and your code is very confusing as such. I'm all for helping but your code must not be an intentional brain teaser

Comment: This code was given in the lecture under the topic of the High-order function. So I think I need to understand the code but like you said it is absolutely a brain teaser.

Comment: You send a function that sends a function the sends a function the executes a function with value 2...

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code looks confusing because the variable names are reused so often.
Let's deconfuse it by changing variable names.

Rename the argument of the inner mask function:

```
def horse(mask):
    horse = mask
    def mask(x):
        return x
    return horse(mask)
```

Rename the inner mask function itself:

```
def horse(mask):
    horse = mask
    def f(x):
        return x
    return horse(f)
```

Now we see the horse function can be simplified:

```
def horse(mask):
    def f(x):
        return x
    return mask(f)
```

Also rename the outer mask function argument:

```
mask = lambda y: y(2)
```

Now it is easy to see that horse(mask) = mask(f) = f(2) = 2

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the code works like this:

> `[mask is the parameter so 2, here present]`

```
def horse (mask)
```

> `[therefore 2 attributed to mask]`

```
horse = mask
```

> `[again 2 in parameter]`

```
def mask (horse)
```

> `[returns 2 because this value has been assigned to the variable horse in the second line]`

```
return horse
```

> `[2 in parameter]`

```
return horse (mask) 

mask = lambda horse: horse (2) `[parameter for the function]`
```

> `[mask result is 2 so the function returns 2]`

```
horse (mask)
```

But it remains very confused

I hope I could help properly!